# Bigcommerce API sort_order

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

The goal of this piece of the project is to allow a customer to rearrange his/her products in whatever list order is desired on a given category page.

I know I can use the "update a category" or "update a product" operations to change the sort_order of the category or product respectively. However, it seems when I set a product sort_order, it sets more of a store-wide priority rather than a specific order in a category. Obviously useful if I want a specific product to return higher in search results, in every category, etc..but what are my options if I want a product high only on a specific category page? Can I define an exact list?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of sort_order is a function of the core app that is unable to be changed based on specific category at this time. There isn't a work around via API that can change this behavior. The best recommendation I could give is using custom category pages per category with custom js to reorder products using a DOMContentLoaded event.

Hopefully that helps. Let me know if you have any more questions.